# Hair problem in Blender 2.93.2 (viewport vs. render)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I have an object covered in multiple hair particle systems with children. They appear fine in the viewport with Cycles (even with the viewport children count set to the render count) but are distorted in the rendered view as seen in the pictures. The object with the hair is small on the final render (the pictures below are highly cropped). Any ideas what can cause this?

I'm rendering on a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 and have already installed the newest driver (4.5.0 NVIDIA 471.68).

[image: difference between viewport and rendered image]

Blender version: 2.93.2, branch: master, commit date: 2021-08-03 05:58, hash: 1eb06de2607a, type: release

CPU: Intel Core i7-6700K

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a different subdiv-level on the emitter object between viewport and render. I am not sure wheather it is a bug or not, but the render is fine when I use the same subdiv-level for the render. The effect may be related to the "Use modifier stack"-option for the hair systems.